# Uploading Rails Apps with MediaTemple

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano, uploading, mediatemple

Any recommendations of a **recent** tutorial, or guide, on uploading Rails applications to a (gs) rails container?

I've followed a couple tutorials already, both of which haven't worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the mt-capistrano gem (from MT) and used [this](http://blog.vixiom.com/2007/02/18/mt-ror-a-z-the-complete-guide-to-getting-rails-running-on-media-temple/) tutorial. It worked just fine for me.

Comment: That's fairly out of date though. I've already had loads of difficulty implementing that method. Are you using the latest versions of rails, capistrano, etc?

Comment: I'm using Rails 2.1 and Capistrano 2.5 with no difficulties. 

I still have to roll my db:migrate(s) manually b/c of some $PATH issues, but I like to see whats going on with my production server anyways.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a how-to a long time ago that someone (apparently) fixed up and got working. I was notified about the post with a pingback not very long ago. Perhaps it will help you get started:

http://websitesyoucanedit.com/?p=102